# MySQL query for dates range. What is wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query?

```
SELECT id_service, creation_date, SUM(ammount)
FROM transactions
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(creation_date, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '08/01/2011'  AND '08/30/2011'
AND id_service = 1
GROUP BY DAY(creation_date)
ORDER BY creation_date
```

I´m taking the transactions between that days range from a particular service -in this case, service 1-, with the total ammount of money for those ocurrences.

Never the less, in the results I´m getting dates from 2010! This is, out from the range.

```
id_service creation_date           ammount
1         2010-08-12 16:57:16   650    <---- WHY 2010???
1         2011-08-01 12:10:01   1735
1         2011-08-02 15:17:12   360
1         2011-08-04 22:05:27   555
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're comparing strings not dates. String `08/12/2010` is indeed between `08/01/2011` and `08/30/2011`

Use

```
WHERE creation_date BETWEEN '2011-08-01'  AND '2011-08-30'
```

instead. Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to format values on right if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
WHERE creation_date BETWEEN '2011-08-01' AND '2011-08-30'
```

You're using date formats that MySQL doesn't recognize as dates, so it's treating them as strings.

Comment: He's actually explicitly converting date to string.

Comment: Yes, and then doing a between comparison, which means STRING parsing rules apply, not date rules.

Comment: I dream of a day where normal people everywhere recognize the wisdom that is ISO 8601.  But seriously, date data types have got you covered!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want to do:

```
SELECT id_service, creation_date, SUM(ammount)
FROM transactions
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(creation_date, '%Y/%m/%d') BETWEEN '2011/08/01'  AND '2011/08/30'
AND id_service = 1
GROUP BY DAY(creation_date)
ORDER BY creation_date
```

You are converting `creation_date` to string starting with a month, so, yes, the 2010 date **is** between the values you provided!

If `creation_date` is actually a date, you could simplify to this:

```
SELECT id_service, creation_date, SUM(ammount)
FROM transactions
WHERE creation_date BETWEEN '2011-08-01'  AND '2011-08-30'
AND id_service = 1
GROUP BY DAY(creation_date)
ORDER BY creation_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You're performing range comparisons on strings.